# Возможно ли сделать подобие ssas на front-end

Tags: php, javascript, css

У меня есть небольшой парсер на php, он "делает всё, что нужно делать" с кодом и отправляет готовый файл пользователю.

---

А возможно ли сделать так, чтобы интерпретация кода происходила уже на фронт энде.
И самый главный вопрос, по сути, в том, как сделать, чтоб js читал файл с css и после обработки применял весь код к сайту...

Comment: А зачем вам sass на frontend?

Comment: Не слишком понятно, что именно вы хотите сделать - "файл пользователю" - какому такому пользователю, кто он такой и зачем ему файл? "Интерпретация" - что это значит для вас в данном контексте и что значит в нем же "фронт енд"?

Answer (score 1):

Для `sass` в этом нет необходимости, обычно... но, да это возможно, есть библиотека на javascript https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/, начать можно здесь https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Для применения стилей можно внедрять `<link >`, `<style>` теги или влиять на элементы `DOM`, это стандартные возможности `JavaScript`

Необходимо помнить, что компиляция `sass` это ресурсоёмкая операция. 
Если приложение небольшое и не нагруженное, почему-бы и нет. Задачи в реальной жизни бывают разные.

```
<script src="dist/sass.js"></script>
<script>
  var scss = '$someVar: 123px; .some-selector { width: $someVar; }';
  sass.compile(scss, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Хмм.. Как я сразу не додумался использовать <style>. Нет, лучше использую свой вариант, весь sass мне не нужен, слишком тяжёлый, а я стремлюсь к минимальному трафику.